# Is Openshift OKD multitenant to external customers or to users?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

Is Openshift OKD meant to be something you can deploy on a per customer basis, so their user's have multitenancy?

Or is it meant to be a single huge openshift okd cluster than you deploy on which all your customers can use it?

Answer (score 2):

If this question is still relevant: Currently, the common multi-tenancy approach is to setup a Kubernetes cluster per customer.

IBM's ICP was designed as multi-tenant environment and OpenShift is likely to develop in that direction (with customer separation by namespaces, seperate LDAPs and clear storage separation). But that's not available, yet.